# m3u8 wrapped mp4 is playing in Exoplayer but can't able to play m3u8 wrapped mp3?

Tags: android, m3u8, exoplayer

while playing m3u8 wrapped mp3 (see error log) but m3u8 wrapped mp4 played well, without any problem

Please help!!!!

**Error log**

```
04-12 11:27:57.375 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
04-12 11:27:57.385 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
04-12 11:27:57.395 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
04-12 11:27:57.395 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
04-12 11:27:57.395 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
04-12 11:27:57.395 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
04-12 11:27:57.425 12210-12210/com.newitventure.bindass I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
04-12 11:27:57.475 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 15(0x3230322e313636),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
04-12 11:27:57.475 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
04-12 11:27:57.805 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 15(0x3230322e313636),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
04-12 11:27:57.805 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
04-12 11:27:58.265 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 15(0x3230322e313636),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
04-12 11:27:58.265 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
04-12 11:27:59.325 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 15(0x3230322e313636),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
04-12 11:27:59.325 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
04-12 11:28:01.355 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 15(0x3230322e313636),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
04-12 11:28:01.355 12210-12448/com.newitventure.bindass D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
04-12 11:28:01.385 12210-12436/com.newitventure.bindass E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
                                                                                 com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: java.io.EOFException
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:263)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:149)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.incrementalPrepareInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:283)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:205)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.io.EOFException at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFromDataSource(DefaultExtractorInput.java:245)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.DefaultExtractorInput.readFully(DefaultExtractorInput.java:67)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ts.TsExtractor.read(TsExtractor.java:127)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.hls.HlsExtractorWrapper.read(HlsExtractorWrapper.java:240)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.hls.TsChunk.load(TsChunk.java:115)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:209)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```